# How to read text files using .equals() for tile maps in java

Tags: java, string, eclipse, char

I'm creating a platformer type game using java and eclipse.  In my game I want to be able to use text files to load levels. Here is the code:

```
public class TileMap {

    Game game;
    Handler handler;
    SpriteSheet ss;

    private int x;
    private int y;

    private int tileSize;
    private int mapWidth;
    private int mapHeight;

    public String block = new String();
    public String player = new String();

    public TileMap(String s, int tileSize, Handler handler, SpriteSheet ss, Game game) {
        this.tileSize = tileSize;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.ss = ss;
        this.game = game;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(s));

            mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            mapHeight = 22;

            String tile[][] = new String[mapWidth][mapHeight];
            String line = new String();

            for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++) {
                line = br.readLine();
                for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++) {
                    char c = line.charAt(col);
                    tile[col][row] = c + "";
                }
            }

            for (int row = 0; row < mapHeight; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < mapWidth; col++) {

                    block = "1";
                    player = "&";

                    if (tile[col][row].equals(block)) {
                        handler.addObject(new Block(col * tileSize, row * tileSize, ID.Block, ss, 1, handler));
                    }

                    if (tile[col][row].equals(player)) {
                        handler.addObject(new Player(col * tileSize, row * tileSize, ID.Player, handler, game, ss, 2));
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
}
```

Right now, I'm just getting a blank screen. Am I using .equals() wrong or is it something else?

Comment: Do you experience any problem? It is not mentioned in the question.

Comment: oh yeah sorry. When it reads "1" it is supposed to spawn a block and when it reads "&"  it is supposed to spawn the player, but I'm getting a black screen.

Comment: You have to debug it. Put breakpoints on `if(tile...)`. Check what `tile[col][row]` actually contains. You compare strings correctly, but it's unclear if `tile[col][row]` contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Also I'd actually change `tile` type to `char[][]` and compare using `==`.